# Не работает сортировка в angular material MatSort

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material

Создаю таблицу с помощью MatTableDataSource, фильтрация работает отлично, а вот сортировка не работает вовсе, никаких ошибок не выдает, все подключено. Подскажите в чем может быть проблема.

```
<div class="table-menu-bar">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="Поик по Imei" (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)">
  </mat-form-field>
</div>  
<div class="table-container">
<table #table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="imei">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Imei </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Imei}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="sim">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Номер sim-карты </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Sim}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-container matColumnDef="deviceTypeName">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Тип устройства </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.DeviceTypeName}} </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="navigate(row.Id)"></mat-row>
</table>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Device, DevicesService } from '../../core/devices.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-devices-list',
  templateUrl: './devices-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./devices-list.component.css']
})
export class DevicesListComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router, private devicesService:DevicesService) { }


  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Device>;
  displayedColumns = ['imei', 'sim', 'deviceTypeName'];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDevice();
  }

  navigate(id: any) {
    this.router.navigate(['app/devices/details/' + id]);
  }

  getDevice() {
    this.devicesService.GetDevices().subscribe(data => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
      this.dataSource.filterPredicate = function(data, filter: string):boolean {
        return data.Imei.includes(filter);
      };
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    })
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Comment: У вас не совпадают имена свойств  `matColumnDef="sim"` и `element.Sim`. Разный регистр первого символа.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, это не имеет значения

Comment: @overthesanity в чем тогда дело?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, возможно не импортирован `MatSortModule`, а вообще на кофейной гуще тяжело гадать, лучше бы человек сделал ссылку на stackblitz

Comment: RaudByorn, покажите ваш модуль

Comment: @overthesanity Гадать, конечно, тяжело. Но мы ведь не боимся трудностей) Если бы не был импортирован модуль, то была бы ошибка в рантайме.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, не было б)

Comment: @overthesanity StepanKasyanenko был прав все дело в именах свойств, они не совпадали и поэтому MatSort не отрабатывал как положено.